# Resources/guidelines on space electronics compliance?

Tags: radiation, testing, electronics, reference-request, compliance

Space hardware suffers from various effects such as radiation, heating, vibration, off-gassing, material degradation and so on. While these effects are mentioned in most space engineering books, I am having a hard time finding resources that help build an understanding of the effects and solutions from the ground up.
Are there any suggested books/courses/papers that can help me understand the process of making a piece of hardware space-compliant, starting from square 1 (or should I say, square 0?). How can I search for the guidelines/rules of compliance used by agencies such as ESA and NASA?

*My background is in analogue/digital electronics and have a fundamental understanding of the space environment.*

Comment: Different but related and potentially helpful: [Is there a space-certification procedure used by commercial spacecraft manufactures for electronic components?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19310/12102) and [Space computing, general question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4922/12102) and [Is there anything like a standard for maximum temperature for mission-critical electronics in spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28304/12102)

Comment: and for some background on "ground up" thinking: [What makes Insight's RAD750 processor so radiation resistant? (compared to 1998 iMac's PowerPC 750)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50470/12102)

Comment: As a side note, "compliance" typically has bureaucratic implications and isn't necessarily grounded in scientific reality (political considerations are just very common especially when the government is involved). That said, it's probably a good place to start even though, particularly in the aerospace industry, the level of engineering required to reach "compliance" is typically firmly in the over-engineered territory.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, much appreciated. Perhaps compliance was not a correct word - I am looking for resources one should study to get into the field of electronics suitable for space on their own. Things like what you do with a PCB to shield it properly, analog circuits that need special attention and so on. Another way to put it would be "what should happen to this common earth prototype with an MCU, some transistors and motors so that it can fly to space "safely" ". Resources I have found so far are either very broad or incredibly specific.